# Kurento: Kurento-room without webcam

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I've seen that [kurento-room](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-room) isn't able of managing a user that enters only with microphone(no webcam). 
The user actually appears in the room, with a black screen in the place where the webcam is normally located, but no audio is received from him either.
Why can this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

That's an error in the connection of WebRTC endpoints. The thing is that the endpoint only negotiates audio, but the connection was made with audio and video profiles, and the media server committed seppuku. It should be fixed by now, providing the right media profiles in the connect method.

Comment: Where has this bug been fixed? In KurentoRoom.js or in the Kurento Media Server?

Comment: In the kurento-room project.